# Ruby script pucking on new line in a file

Tags: ruby

If I only have one host in the file the scripts does as intended. As soon as I add another address in the file I get this error. I understand that it does not like the new line character at the end of the first host in the file, how is this problem alleviated? I'm basically looking for the script to run down the hostfile, and for every address or host-name in the file, run the session.

`'initialize': newline at the end of hostname`

```
File.read('hostfile').each_line do |hostname|
  session = Net::SSH.start(hostname, @username, :password => @password, :encryption => 'aes256-cbc', :host_key => 'ssh-rsa')
  cmd_session = Net::SSH::Telnet.new('Session' => session)
  cmd_session.cmd("en\r#{@enable}")
  cmd_session.cmd('terminal pager 0')
  cmd_session.cmd('show threat-detection statistics') { |c| print c }
  cmd_session.close
end
```

Comment: `session = Net::SSH.start(hostname.strip, @username.....` should get you going.

Comment: @Anand, if you post that as an answer, instead of a comment, then the original poster can Accept it. And you get points.

Comment: @Anand answer not in comments)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session = Net::SSH.start(hostname.strip, @username.....`

Should get you going. For further reference see the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-strip)